# Server.MapPath C# works locally but not from live server

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]Having a big of an issue with with Server.MapPath in that I can't get it to resolve from server.
I am getting certificate file in folder ,Locally, it works fine in a whole variety of different ways, but when I put it up to the server it shows an error "The Specified file path not found"

MyCode in .aspx.cs file:

```
  var certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Push/testkeys/Certificates.p12");
```

var push = new PushNotification(true, certificatePath, "mobile");

.cs file:

```
public PushNotification(bool useSandbox, string p12File, string p12FilePassword)
    {
        if (useSandbox)
        {
            _host = SandboxHost;
            _feedbackHost = SandboxFeedbackHost;
        }
        else
        {
            _host = ProductionHost;
            _feedbackHost = ProductionFeedbackHost;
        }
        _certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12File, p12FilePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        _certificates = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection { _certificate };

        // Loading Apple error response list.
        _errorList.Add(0, "No errors encountered");
        _errorList.Add(1, "Processing error");
        _errorList.Add(2, "Missing device token");
        _errorList.Add(3, "Missing topic");
        _errorList.Add(4, "Missing payload");
        _errorList.Add(5, "Invalid token size");
        _errorList.Add(6, "Invalid topic size");
        _errorList.Add(7, "Invalid payload size");
        _errorList.Add(8, "Invalid token");
        _errorList.Add(255, "None (unknown)");
    }
```

Comment: Then that directory doesn't exist on the server. Set the build action for the `.p12` file to copy.

Comment: but i upload all folders and certificate file in tat folder "~/Push/testkeys/Certificates.p12". i CHecked  it available.

Comment: Have you tried using HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Push/testkeys/Certificates.p12");

Comment: More specifically, does the application pool that the live application run as have rights to read from the `testkeys` folder?